# Trigonometric inequality $\sin x\geq\frac{4\delta}{\pi}$ for $x\in(\delta,\pi/2]$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I read that if $0<\delta<t\leq\pi$ then $$\sin\frac{t}{2}\geq\frac{2\delta}{\pi}.$$I am ashamed in asking this because it looks like and easy trigonometric inequality, but I cannot see how it is verified. Of course we can set $x=t/2$ and say that for all $0<\delta<x\leq\pi/2$ the inequality$$\sin x\geq\frac{4\delta}{\pi}$$holds, but I do not find it easier to prove this last one... Could anybody explain how it is derived? I thank you all very much!

*EDIT*: In order that the reader does not interiorise a false proposition, I warn here that the inequality does not hold as it is written: see comments and answers.

Comment: Don't be ashamed to ask questions! Everyone has things they don't understand the first time.

Comment: If you let $\delta$ increase, then you'd get $\sin x\geq\frac{4x}{\pi}$, but this is not true for $x \in [0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: you probably mean $$\sin x \ge \frac{2\delta}{\pi}$$
which can be easily seen by drawing the graphs of the functions $\sin x$ and $\frac{2}{\pi}x$ on the interval $[0, \pi/2]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality 
$$
\sin\frac{t}{2}\geq\frac{2\delta}{\pi}
$$
does not hold $t=\pi/2$ and $\delta=5/4$ even though $0<\delta<t\leq\pi$.

On the other hand, when $0<\delta<x\leq\pi/2$, it *is* true that
$$
\sin x\geq\frac{2\delta}{\pi}
$$
because
$$
\sin x\geq\frac{2x}{\pi}
$$
in that interval (see @Mher's comment).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I suspect there is a printing error in Kolmogorov-Fomin's, then...

Comment: @DavideZena, do you have a Google Book link to that page?

Comment: p. 417, 4$^\text{th}$ line here (in Russian, I know no on-line English translation): http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf